# Reference Function Defined in a ScriptBlock from Another Context

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to call a function declared inside a scriptblock outside of the scriptblock but PS can't resolve it.  Here's my code

```
  $ScriptBlock={

        function Get-Baz(){

            Write-Host "Baz executed"
        }
        function Get-Foo(){
            Write-Host "Foo executed"
        }
    }

    Get-Baz <--The term 'Get-Baz' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a script block doesn't execute anything inside of it.

Usually you execute a scriptblock with [the call operator `&`](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) but that executes it in a different scope and won't work.

Instead, you need to execute the scriptblock in the current scope. To do that, use the [dot sourcing operator `.`](https://ss64.com/ps/source.html):

```
$ScriptBlock={

    function Get-Baz(){

        Write-Host "Baz executed"
    }
    function Get-Foo(){
        Write-Host "Foo executed"
    }
}

. $ScriptBlock

Get-Baz
```